# Update column values not possible when a trigger is attached to that table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I'm trying to do a simple Update statement to fix some data in my database like the following:

```
UPDATE SalesTable
   SET ProductId = NULL
 WHERE ProductId = 0
```

I just want to switch any value of 0 back to a null.  The column is nullable and there are some null records already.  The problem seems to be that I have a trigger attached to the SalesTable that fires when an update to that table is made.  It doesn't seem to like the fact that my update statement is updating multiple rows at once.  How do I get around this?

Here is the error message if that helps:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows `=, !=, <, <= , >, >=` or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Here's a dumbed down version of the trigger.  Not sure if it matters or not, but the ProductId field isn't being used in the trigger.

```
DECLARE @salesId int
DECLARE @salesDate DateTime2
DECLARE @customerName varchar(50)

SELECT  @salesId = s.SalesId, 
        @salesDate = s.SalesDate, 
        @customerName = c.CustomerName  
FROM Inserted s 
INNER JOIN Customer c 
    ON s.CustomerId = c.CustomerId

UPDATE SalesSummary 
SET SalesId = @salesId, 
    SalesDate = @salesDate, 
    CustomerName = @customerName
WHERE SalesId = @salesId
```

Comment: the trigger text is relevant here.  # of rows updated is irrelevant as each row updated would fire the trigger.  The problem is I think in the trigger itself because a subquery within the trigger is not returning a unique record.  We'd need to see the text within the update portion of the trigger.

Comment: I edited my post to add a dumbed down version of the trigger code.  And you're right, it seems like the problem is I'm getting the data from "inserted" and "inserted" is multiple records which is causing it to fail.  I can't change the trigger due to management reasons, so I'm trying to come up with an Update statement to bypass this restriction.  I know I could do a cursor and loop through and update each record individually, but there has to be a better/easier way, right?

Comment: Your trigger code here seems to have a MAJOR flaw. Your code will not handle multiple row operations. It is critical in a trigger to have set based code. When you have scalar values like this you cannot accurately handle that.

Comment: Why is this a major flaw?  This trigger has been working fine for me for a couple years now.  There will never be a time in the system when multiple records will be updated at the same time.  This is the first time I'm coming across this issue and it's because I'm trying to fix some data.

Comment: If this is a one time run and done, put an exclusive lock on the table, disable/delete the trigger, run your script, re-enable/create trigger remove exclusive lock.  All wrapped in a transaction should take a few seconds to execute and systems back.  If the table has 0 use at some time you can avoid the exclusive lock but you run the risk of the trigger not firing when new data is inserted... while you're doing this; otherwise you have to do separate calls for each record needing to be updated allowing you to leave the trigger in place.

Comment: Thanks xQbert, the system will be offline when the script is run so I don't need to lock the table.  So something like this would work? ALTER TABLE SalesTable DISABLE TRIGGER SalesTrigger

UPDATE SalesTable
   SET ProductId = NULL
 WHERE ProductId = 0

ALTER TABLE SalesTable ENABLE TRIGGER SalesTrigger

Comment: It should, provided nothing else prevents the update.  Like a 2nd trigger on the same table, some sort of unique index or key constraint...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to xQbert for leaving a comment under my question that solved my issue without having to rewrite my trigger.  His solution was to disable the trigger, make the update, and then re-enable the trigger after the update.  Since my system will be turned off when I run the update this will work fine.  However if you have the same issue in a live system, you should put a lock on the table when doing this as well.

```
ALTER TABLE SalesTable DISABLE TRIGGER SalesTrigger

UPDATE SalesTable
  SET ProductId = NULL
WHERE ProductId = 0

ALTER TABLE SalesTable ENABLE TRIGGER SalesTrigger
```

Comment: +1 Excellent job taking your comment with correct syntax and making an answer of it.  I'm thrilled you received the needed guidance and were to develop the solution yourself.  (and incase people think this way, no this isn't sarcasm)

Answer (score 0):

In your trigger you may have condition like this :

```
where ProductID = (Select ProductId From SalesTable)
```

See if you can change it to

```
where ProductID IN (Select ProductId From SalesTable)
```

and yes the trigger text is relevant here.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If you check my post again, I added the trigger code.  I believe the problem is in the trigger that I'm getting the values from "inserted".  That works fine if only 1 record is being updated at a time.  If I update multiple at a time, it can't get the value from "inserted".

Answer (score 0):

```
    -- Here's your problem
    SELECT   @salesId = s.SalesId, 
         @salesDate = s.SalesDate, 
         @customerName = c.CustomerName  
    FROM     Inserted s INNER JOIN Customer c on s.CustomerId = c.CustomerId

    UPDATE SalesSummary SET  
        SalesId = @salesId,
                        SalesDate = @salesDate,
        CustomerName = @customerName
    WHERE   SalesId = @salesId
```

Using @salesId as an example -
When updating one record (say salesId 1) @salesId is properly assigned to from inserted

However when multiple rows are updated at once, say 1,2,3,4,5, @salesId being an integer cannot take row data as its assignment.

I think you could get around this by running your update statements in a loop, doing one row at a time.  But the real solution would be to update the trigger.  I'm sure we could offer some suggestions on how to do so - though you stated you can't update the trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was thinking of doing a loop as well, but I was hoping for an easier way.  Another user posted a solution in a comment that I chose to use.  He suggested disabling the trigger, running the statement, and then enabling the trigger again.